# "For" for files with spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The question seems to be pretty easy, but I haven't found solution myself.

I have some folder, with 1 jpg-file inside it (foo bar.jpg) and this bat-file:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /a:-d "*.jpg"') do echo "%%f"
pause
```

For some reason instead of something like this:

```
C:\Test>echo foo bar.jpg
foo bar.jpg
```

I see this:

```
C:\Test>echo "foo"
"foo"
```

Despite I already put `%%f` inside quotes.

I.e. command prompt doesn't understand the space in file name.

How to fix it?

(In my real code I will use `copy` instead of `echo`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `help for`.

`for /f` splits the results into tokens, based on the default or supplied delims.  You need something like:

```
for /f "delims=" ....
```

Should capture the entire output.  Another option is:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G ... do echo %%G
```

Comment: For the second approach, why use two variables? How about `for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a:-d "*.jpg"') do (echo %%f)`

Comment: @lit, never actually tried that until just now actually.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

For me works:

```
for /f  "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /A:-D "*.jpg"') do @echo %%f
```

and returns:

```
foo bar.jpg
```